# Should I use REST or another mechanism in this scenario

Tags: c#, django, rest, tastypie

I'm working on a Django web app that lets a user create and display records about servers on networks. Each server record has fields such as server name, IP address, services running etc.

The URL for a specific server entry is, for example, https://mywebservice.com/servers/53/ , where 53 is an id created by the web service for that server record when it was created.

I want to write a simple agent (in c#) that locally collects information about servers and sends the results to the Django web app.

I was thinking a RESTFUL solution using Tastypie  would be the right way to go, but I am confused about how I would send the data.

For example, say there is already an entry for a server with a URL of   https://mywebservice.com/servers/53/.

How would my simple agent  know that it should use the id 53 and update the record.

I would like my agent to be able to simply collect the server data and send results to the web service; and let the web service work out if a new record should be created or an existing one updated.

Is this breaking the RESTFUL model? Is it possible to do this using Tastypie? Would another mechanism be more appropriate?

Comment: Is your "Simple Agent" going to be completely client side? If so it has no knowledge of what the server does with the data you send. In your case https://mywebservice.com/servers/53/ could do anything under the sun.

Comment: Yes, the agent is going to be completely client side and send data to server. At the moment mywebservice.com/servers/53 displays the record with id 53 to a user of my web app and lets them update it.

Comment: Ok I think you may want to rewrite your question as im not really sure what you want. Do you need to know how to send a REST message to a server?

Comment: Yes I wan to know if I can use Tastypie to REST enable the app described and send data to it with my simple agent. When I looked at REST / Tastypie it seemed to need the client to know about IDs. I could be mistaken though.

Comment: Well ya. You cant do a REST request to a server without knowing what you are requesting. In your case you need to know the ID number.